# NON-UEFI and alongside with Windows... cann't choose Windows in boot menu

Tags: boot, windows, uefi

I have installed now Ubuntu 16.
I explicitly chosen no-uefi installation and checked Alongside with Windows.
After installation I can't see Windows in boot menu.

How to retrieve Windows?

Thanks

Comment: Was Windows installed in legacy also? Unlikely if factory installed. You must always install in the same way the previous OS was for a proper dual boot.

Comment: "I explicitly chosen no-uefi installation" why? why not pick the same as windows was installed with? That would be the correct method ;) What you say here either means you should have picked UEFI or you removed windows.

Comment: Omg... I just placed Windows 7 DVD into computer, because I don't have Win10, restarted it and press F12 for boot menu. Suddenly Windows Loader option appered. I entered into Windows 10. Can someone explain me this?!

Comment: I don't even know what UEFI is :D I am total beginner!

Comment: Start by reading this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI . Again, if your Windows is factory installed then it is in UEFI mode.

Comment: When you boot your computer a screen appears for a few seconds doing the POST (Power On Self Test). During this time a splash screen appears with options such as F2 to enter `BIOS Setup`. Choose this option to see if your computer is setup for Legacy or UEFI (Universal Extended Format Interface (I think)) boot option. I've never used EFI but if your BIOS is set that way you have to install Ubuntu the same way and hopefully an expert can provide an answer.  BTW Welcome to AskUbuntu! PS posting your computer make and model lets us tell you which Fx key to press to enter BIOS setup.

Comment: @user8915 Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may need to reinstall Ubuntu, but _this_ time, be sure to install it in UEFI mode. A modern version of Windows requires UEFI mode, so any other OSes on your computer will need to be installed in that mode as well

Comment: I told you... I put Windows disc into DVDROM and I've got option to boot into Windows. I am interested now how to repair grub menu.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork. (Note that others' answers in comments may be correct, but they *are* making assumptions about your configuration.)

Comment: Thanks everyone! I haven't logged in to Askubuntu some time :) Since then, I was using Windows, but now again back to Ubuntu 16.04. I installed it this time sucessfully :) Kind regards